# Find name of smallest file in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesize

Suppose that you have to find the name of the 4th smallest (non-hidden) file in the directory

What is the right command to do this? Suppose I'm a guy who only knows `ls -l`, `head`, `tail`, `line`, and `awk '{print}'` statement.

Answer (score 3):

From `man ls`: `-S` sorts the output by size descending, `-r` reverses the order of the output

So my solution would look like

```
ls -rS | sed -n '4p'
```

or, alternatively

```
ls -rS | awk 'NR==4'
```

Comment: so how would the command be if i had to find the 4th biggest file for instance? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Parsing `ls` is [not safe](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) because it is difficult and error prone to handle strange characters like spaces and newlines in filenames.

I would recommend using the following approach which is more robust since it uses null-terminated line endings.

```
count=0
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
    ((++count == 4)) && echo "${line#* }" && break
done < <(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -printf '%s %p\0' | sort -zn)
```

Comment: It is not the case that parsing `ls` is unsafe.  It is the case that using spaces, newlines, and control characters in filenames is a bad decision.

Comment: @EarlGray Files will be printed out twice if you use `printf` and `print0` in the same `find` command.