# Listing smallest files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can you print the 6 smallest files in /usr/bin directory for Shell?

```
ls /usr/bin
```

I know that this shows all the files that is in that directory but I just don't know to to print out the 6 smallest files.

What would be a one line command for this process on the command line for Shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find name of smallest file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15497965/608639), [How to find the largest file in a directory and its subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12522269/608639), etc.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
ls -SrqL /usr/bin | head -6
```

> `-S` makes it sorted by file size
>
> `-r` for reverse order
>
> `-q` to print ? instead of nongraphic characters (line breaks included)
>
> `-L`   when showing file information for a symbolic link, this shows information for the file the link references rather than for the link itself
>
> `head` Shows the 6 first lines of the previous output

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Cyrus you are faster than your own shadow. @user10752715 only mentioned printing. So `ls -Sr` and even `head -6` is quite harmless.

Comment: @Cyrus. What's the relevance?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: It is not guaranteed that the output contains six file names, because line breaks in file names are allowed.

Comment: You're right @Cyrus, I added -q parameter

Comment: With GNU: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s %f\0" | sort -z -rn | head -z -n 6 | cut -z -d ' ' -f 2- | tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: @Cyrus That solution does not include those files that have line breaks in their names. It also does not print the smallest, only the biggest.

Comment: @Carlos: I don't agree with that statement. Remove `| head -z -n 6` and you should see all files in current directory.

Comment: @Carlos Your command includes symbolic links as well. I ran the command and it listed all the first 6 links which are smallest in size however the actual file link is pointing to is bigger. I think we should exclude links.

Comment: @Cyrus yep, my bad. I made several files in order to test it and those with line breaks were not shown because of the order (I made them the smallest). Make a new answer with that solution fixing the order because it's a good answer.

Comment: @Carlos: No problem. Bug: In my example, you have to remove the `-r` from `sort` to reverse the wrong sorting.

Comment: @Pacifist Agree with that. I don't know how to exclude them so I add -L to show information about the file it's referencing to, not the link itself.

Comment: @Carlos we might need something like this : ls -Srql /usr/bin|egrep -v "^l"|head -6|awk '{print $5,$9}'|sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'

Answer (score 2):

List the six smallest files in current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s %f\0" | sort -z -n | head -z -n 6 | cut -z -d ' ' -f 2- | tr '\0' '\n'
```

- This only lists files
- It can handle all special characters in file names, even line breaks.